# Seeing various user icons as 'missing'

Tags: support

For various users (not sure how long this has been happening), I am seeing a broken image rather than the proper icon...
[image]

If I inspect the image I get some error messages for the page...

```
AOh14Gj_J1OSe7HXBH_uneDFYvmn9rwKWH0kPBkFDmg35A=s96-c=k-s32:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
AOh14GgoZqTUqL46AZcIbsiBt6q-OGSjpI6j5KrGEzeb=s96-c=k-s32:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

The link is something like https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gg6LVxU2ZpyVUqThmTOa-BhVnH2GErSSKqVCqb2Dw=s96-c=k-s32 (not the same link as above though) and try to access this URL gives me a page with

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.

Any ideas why?  One theory I had is that I'm not logged into Google, but this shouldn't make a difference as this isn't a requirement of SO (AFAIK).

Comment: External links die - profile pics stored in an SSO system isn't an exception. They're not updated if they die either

Comment: cross site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355948/invalid-size-parameters-break-avatars-served-by-google

Comment: I think the image was deleted or that it didn't follow the copyright laws.

Comment: @rene, is it worth just deleting this question or should I leave it?

Comment: I would leave it. I assume more people will find/notice this bug and will post/search here. We can close those new reports against this one. Your report contains enough info to be a good dupe target.